# ReSharper - no curly braces for single line terminating statement

Tags: c#, resharper

How to make Re-sharper to distinguish between terminating (return, throw exception, break/continue) and all other statements, to remove curly brackets for terminating only?

The company code standards are that braces must be present around single-line statement, except when a statements terminates.

So braces here:

```
if (condition)
{
   DoSmth();
}
```

But no braces:

```
if (condition)
   return GetSmth();
```

Number of terminating single-line statements in my code is much higher than non-terminations ones, so I set "Remove Braces" for all Force Braces settings in "Code Editing"=>"C#"=>"Formatting Style"=>"Braces Layout", and getting comments on code review stage for missing braces for single line statements. I go and adjust them manually, but running Cleanup Code tool removes these braces again.

I need any combination of settings/formatting rules which allows to follow  company code standards with minimal efforts and minimizes manual formatting.

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem?